Why am I getting a path not found? php include not finding the file, ide is visual studio code
I have a file structure as such  root project folder/assets/css
/stewarship
/view
in /view is header.php, my header and nav bar. the header.php file finds the css file fine with the path /assets/css/styles.css
here is the header.php code it works fine
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>About Us - Shepherd Digital Parish Services</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/styles.css">
</head>
   
   <header>
        <h1>Shepherd Digital Parish Services</h1>
        <h3>Guide Your Flock into the Digital Pasture</h3>
        <div class="navbar">
           
            <a href='/index.php'>Home</a>
             <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="dropbtn">Services
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="/stewardship.php">Stewardship</a>
                <a href="/digevan.php">Evangelization</a>
                <a href="/engagement.php">Engagement</a>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
</header>

in stewardship I have a file givingreports.php in that file I have a php include to pull in the header
<body>
    <?php include 'assets/view/header.php'; ?>
</body>

Visual Studio Code says it is the correct path but when I load it up in a browser I get a php error of path not found.
pages in the root project folder find the header just fine.
here is a picture of the file structure

I have tried adding /../ ../
I have tried the full path.
Update: have tried all suggestions so far. here is the full code of givingreports.php also attaching a screenshot to show what VSC believes the path to be P:\my name\SYF\assets\view\header.php which is correct but the error message displays Failed opening 'assets/view/header.php'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Shepherd Digital Parish Services</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/styles.css">
    </head>
<body>
<?php include 'assets/view/header.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>


what path are you using in givingreports.php?

Please provide actual code not just descriptions. See [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. Thanks

Stephen I tried that

Using relative paths when including can be tricking, you really have to know what you're doing. An easy solution can be to use absolute paths. The magic constant __DIR__ can help. So, try something like <?php include __DIR__ . '/view/header.php'; ?> in the file givingreports.php?

Https://phpdelusions.net/paths
